# How I can check two dataTable objects to contain a value in the other DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, row, contains

hi I have two DataTable objects and I want to control this two DataTables step by step:

For example here are two DataTable:

```
DataTable "zugang"

Name
A
B
C
D

DataTable "abgang"

Name
C
D
E
F
```

step 1: zugang columnvalue contains abgang coummvalue
Herre I create a new DataTable "complete" with columns name and status

To Control: zugang

```
A is not in abgang -> addRow(name=A,status=new)
B is not in abgang -> addRow(name=B,status=new)
C is in abgang     -> addRow(name=C,status=change)
D is in abgang     -> addRow(name=D,status=change)
```

step2: abgang columnvalue not contains zugang columnvalue

to Control: abgang

```
C is in zugang -> nothing
D is in zugang -> nothing
E is not in zugang -> addRow(name=E,status=delete)
F is not in zugang -> addRow(name=F,status=delete)
```

after this steps the new DataTable must be how this:

```
Name | Status
A      new
B      new
C      change
D      change
E      delete
F      delete
```

So I can final count the rows with this three status values :)

```
and I get -> new=2 , change=2 and delete=2
```

Here is my methode structure:

```
private static DataTable ControlDataTable(DataTable zugang, DataTable abgang) 
{
    DataTable endTable;

    //addcolumns 
    step 1:

    step2:

    return endtable;
}
```

Comment: Where you get table data?

Comment: Looks like a pretty straight forward thing to do. What did you try? Where are you having issue?